# Rotating image inside a border

Tags: c#, xaml

Hi,

I have a image inside a Border which I would provide an angle for. Currently I am just hard coding it to 45.

My problem is that the image is displayed at the left of the border. I want it to be in the centre and fit inside the border. 
When I provide an angle I want it to rotate inside the border.

```
        <Grid Background="gray" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="36" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Line Grid.Column="0" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="0" Y2="500" Fill="Black" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="7" StrokeDashArray="0.5 0.5"
                />
            <Border  Grid.Column="1" Background="DarkGreen"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"   >


                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication3;component/Resources/MyImage.png">
                    <Image.RenderTransform >
                        <RotateTransform Angle="45" />
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image >



            </Border>
            <Line  Grid.Column="2" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="0" Y2="5000" Fill="Black" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="7" StrokeDashArray="0.5 0.5"
                />

        </Grid>
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Set the `RenderTransformOrigin` property to the center of the image. RenderTransformOrigin uses relative coordinates, hence the center is at `0.5,0.5`:

```
<Border ClipToBounds="True">
    <Image ... RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Border>
```

In order to fit the rotated Image in the Border control, you could set its `LayoutTransform`:

```
<Border>
    <Image ...>
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
    </Image>
</Border>
```

Comment: But how will the image resize itself as the width and the height of the border is unknown

Comment: You could set LayoutTransform instead of RenderTransform. See my edit.

Comment: LayoutTransform does not Stretch the image. Try angle like 120 or 160

Comment: It isn't clear what you are actually trying to achieve. Please add some details to your question, possibly a sketch of the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CenterX and CenterY properties of RotateTransform to set the center of rotation.
If you need the image to expand the border size when rotating you need to use LayoutTransform.

For instance it could be done as:

```
        <Border>
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication3;component/Resources/MyImage.png" x:Name="image">
                <Image.RenderTransform >
                    <RotateTransform 
                        Angle="45" 
                        CenterX="{Binding ElementName=image, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=DivideBy2Converter}}"
                        CenterY="{Binding ElementName=image, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=DivideBy2Converter}}"
                        />
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image >
        </Border>
```

**Edit:**
Take ActualSize of image, not border

Comment: Yes but my border is of auto size width, hence I do not know what values should I give in centerx and centery

Comment: You could probably use bindings and appropriate converters

Comment: If the RenderTransformOrigin is center by default. Just add ClipToBounds=True to Border, and Stretch enumeration of "UniformToFill", eg;  ....that is if I'm understanding the intended result correctly.

Comment: RenderTransormOrigin is not center by default. It's top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make an image similar to a clock arm. Given the angle it would just display it. The problem was that the image was not stretching at 120 or 160 and the arm would become shorter.

I finally achieved by making a rectangle and calculating its margins and CenterY

```
        <Rectangle 
    Stroke="yellow" Fill="Yellow">
            <Rectangle.Margin>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MarginConverter}">
                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        <Binding ElementName="border" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="border" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Rectangle.Margin>
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="0" 
            CenterY="{Binding ElementName=border, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource CalculateRectCenterY}}" Angle="120" />
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
```

Michał Żochowski's post gave me the idea although his answer did not solve me problem exactly